# Z3 Java API - get unsat core

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving

I am trying to figure out how to get the unsat core using the Java API for Z3. Our scenario is as follows (code is underneath, which works in rise4fun):

1. We create the SMT2 input programtically
2. The input contains function definitions, datatype declarations, and assertions
3. We parse this using the parseSMTLIB2String API
4. We ensure that the context and the solver have unsat_core -> true
5. Z3 returns UNSAT for the provided input, which is correct
6. The UNSAT core is always empty though.
7. The same input produces an UNSAT core correctly on rise4fun (x1 x3)

I am guessing I am misusing the API somehow... but not quite sure how/why.

I have noticed that I cannot set the unsat core option in the SMT string that I pass to parseSMTLIB2String, because that is not allowed. I am guessing that is expected.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!!

```
(set-option :smt.macro-finder true)

;; The following is only for rise4fun, i cannot get it 
;; to work with the parse SMT Java API
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)

(define-sort Ref () Int)

(declare-datatypes (T1 T2) ((Tuple2 (mk-Tuple2 (_1 T1)(_2 T2)))))
(declare-datatypes (T1 T2 T3) ((Tuple3 (mk-Tuple3 (_1 T1)(_2 T2)(_3 T3)))))

(define-sort Set (T) (Array T Bool))
(define-sort Bag (T) (Array T Int))

(declare-const emptySetOf_Int (Set Int))
(assert (!(forall ((x Int)) (= (select emptySetOf_Int x) false)) :named AXIOM1))

(declare-sort TopLevelDeclarations) (declare-const mk-TopLevelDeclarations TopLevelDeclarations)
(declare-datatypes () ((A (mk-A (x Int)(y Int)))))

(declare-datatypes () ((Any
  (lift-TopLevelDeclarations (sel-TopLevelDeclarations TopLevelDeclarations))
  (lift-A (sel-A A))
  null))
)

(declare-const heap (Array Ref Any))

(define-fun deref ((ref Ref)) Any
  (select heap ref)
)

(define-fun deref-is-TopLevelDeclarations ((this Ref)) Bool
  (is-lift-TopLevelDeclarations (deref this))
)

(define-fun deref-TopLevelDeclarations ((this Ref)) TopLevelDeclarations
  (sel-TopLevelDeclarations (deref this))
)

(define-fun deref-is-A ((this Ref)) Bool
  (is-lift-A (deref this))
)

(define-fun deref-A ((this Ref)) A
  (sel-A (deref this))
)

(define-fun deref-isa-TopLevelDeclarations ((this Ref)) Bool
  (deref-is-TopLevelDeclarations this)
)

(define-fun deref-isa-A ((this Ref)) Bool
  (deref-is-A this)
)

(define-fun A!x ((this Ref)) Int
  (x (deref-A this))
)

(define-fun A!y ((this Ref)) Int
  (y (deref-A this))
)

(define-fun TopLevelDeclarations.inv ((this Ref)) Bool
  true
)

(assert (! (forall ((this Ref))
  (=> (deref-is-TopLevelDeclarations this) (TopLevelDeclarations.inv this))
) :named x0))

(define-fun A.inv ((this Ref)) Bool
  (and
    (> (A!x this)  0)
    (> (A!y this)  0)
    (< (A!x this)  0)
  )
)

(assert (! (forall ((this Ref))
  (=> (deref-is-A this) (A.inv this))
) :named x1))

(assert (!(deref-is-TopLevelDeclarations 0) :named TOP))
(assert (!(exists ((instanceOfA Ref)) (deref-is-A instanceOfA)) :named x3))

(check-sat)
(get-unsat-core)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the Java API, except for the call to `parseSMTLIB2String`. This function does not execute any SMT commands and there is no function that would do that for you. `parseSMTLIB2String` exists exclusively to parse assertions, it will ignore everything else. For this particular problem, I recommend to simply pass the problem file to `z3.exe` either as a command line argument or via stdin (use `-in` option). This produces

```
unsat
(x1 x3)
```

If the intent is to use the Java API for other things at a later point, see the [Java API unsat core example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/java/JavaExample.java#L2078).

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. I just left it out but we add the returned BoolExpr to a solver created from the context and then use the API to check. Passing it to Z3.exe is fine, but we are actually also interested in cases where the model is SAT and then parse the model returned from Z3, which I think is difficult when just calling z3.exe. Or is that not correct?

Comment: That's a matter of perspective... models are relatively easy to parse too (just add (get-model) after (check-sat) to dump them), but it's a little bit more complicated than parsing the unsat core output. Personally I prefer doing those things through the API.

Comment: Yes, we are using the API to get the model and then parse it. So, my question still remains: how come I don't see the UNSAT core when using the Java API getUnsatCore...

Comment: Is it the fact that I never actually create bool constants using the API - I just use the returned BoolExp and pass it to the solver... ?

Comment: I confirmed that because I am not creating the boolean constants and expressions (so I have no symbols), the unsat core does not work. A little bit unintuitive, because I would have thought that the parse API would suck the names in... So I have switched to using the Z3 executable in this case. Thanks, Christoph.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The parser is really just for the convenience of parsing simple expressions. I think it does parse the names, but there are a few other options that need to be enabled so that unsat cores work (e.g., unsat_core=true on the context and/or goals, because the parser will not execture the set-option commands).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found that it depends on how you pass the parsed input to the solver.

While the following approach produces an empty unsat-core...:

```
BoolExpr[] program = context.parseSMTLIB2File(input_file, null, null, null, null);
solver.add(program);
solver.check();
solver.getUnsatCore();
```

... the unsat-core is produced correctly if you give the parsed input file to the solver as follows:

```
BoolExpr[] program = context.parseSMTLIB2File(input_file, null, null, null, null);
solver.check(program);
solver.getUnsatCore();
```

I therefore assume that everything that is passed via `solver.add()` belongs to the assumptions and therefore presumably does not belong to the unsat-core according to Z3.